# ordering items in a list but keep getting AttributeError

Tags: python, django, list, django-views, attributeerror

I am trying to organise all the posts in this list that I've created in order by descending 'created'.

This is my function:

```
def posts_search_by_following(request, user_username):
    start = int(request.GET.get('start') or 0)
    end = int(request.GET.get('end') or (start + 9))

    profile = get_object_or_404(User, username=user_username)
    following_users = profile.get_following()
    posts = list()[start:end]
    for person in following_users:
        posts += Post.objects.filter(creator=person).order_by('-created')


    return JsonResponse(
        {'posts': [post.serialize() for post in posts]}
    )
```

As it is right now, it is only ordering posts by their 'created' field per person. So when the whole list is returned everything isn't all in order. However if I try to move `.order_by('created')` anywhere else:

```
{'posts': [post.serialize() for post in posts].order_by('created')}
```

it will give me an Attribute error like this:

```
AttributeError at /posts/Moderator/following/search
'list' object has no attribute 'order_by'
```

How can I get the total number of posts and then order them accordingly?

Comment: `.sort()` does look like exactly what I need but when I try to use it like this: `return JsonResponse(
        {'posts': [post.serialize() for post in posts.sort()]}
    )` I get a type error like this`'<' not supported between instances of 'Post' and 'Post'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this does not work is because your `posts` is a *list*, not a `QuerySet`, and a list has no [**`.order_by(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) method. You can query all the `Post`s of all the persons with a single query:

```
def posts_search_by_following(request, user_username):
    start = int(request.GET.get('start') or 0)
    end = int(request.GET.get('end') or (start + 9))

    profile = get_object_or_404(User, username=user_username)
    following_users = profile.get_following()
    posts = Post.objects.filter(
        creator__in=following_users
    ).order_by('-created')[start:end]


    return JsonResponse(
        {'posts': [post.serialize() for post in posts]}
    )
```